# Design Patterns Vs EffectiveJava

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am student striving to improve my Java and general programming skills. I am familiar with some of the basic design patterns.

I have two books on my disposal "Head First to Design Patterns" and "Effective Java"(Josh Bloch), both aiming to promote good programming practices.

However I am confused as to "how should I read the texts so that it makes the most sense?"

From what I understand, design patterns are basics and effective java has some addon practices in addition to general design patterns.

What is the right way to look on the entire scenario?

Comment: Jeff says ... http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/09/head-first-design-patterns.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just have to build your knowledge up.  Some of that is by reading good books, of which the Josh Bloch book is a very good book.  Some of it is by taking on programming tasks in your spare time and keeping an eye on blogs and other websites such as stackoverflow.  While some of it you will get through other practical experience i.e. at work.

These things take time and come with experience.  Just enjoy the language and immerse yourself in it.  Patterns aren't the be all and end all of the language - they're part of an effective toolkit though. It's better to understand the language fully, then you will see how design patterns can help solve common problems and often solve them better.  But definitely don't get obsessed by patterns, until you know the language well enough.  If fact don't get obsessed by patterns at all!

I'd say the Josh Bloch book is the best book to concentrate on 1st - it's excellent and introduces you to all the key concepts (common methods such as equals and hashcode, enums, concurrency)  and also introduces patterns which you'll get day to day benefits from e.g. Builder pattern.

Comment: Thanks! I will concentrate on Effective Java first and start with it.

Answer (score 8):

> However I am confused as to "how should I read the texts so that it makes the most sense?"

My only advice is to **avoid overkill and over-engineering**. Some experienced OOP (and Java) programmers that learn design patters taking them as they were the Bible often create fuzzy and useless code. That seems contradictory, but if you think about it, it isn't.

When the goal of programming is no longer resolving a problem, producing useful tools, and having measurable results, but becomes the **exposition of one's great sophistication, cleverness, and sometimes smartass egotism**, then the code becomes just a bunch of tricky brainwave that is useless to anybody, excluding the one who wrote the code and feels good looking at his crazy "white elephant".

Many times I've seen useless applications of them. The most abused is the factory pattern, that in this moment is quite trendy and in fact put everywhere like a food dressing.

Many times I've seen proliferation of classes and interfaces, useless generalizations, which are pointless: in some cases I've seen packages with 2 useful classes, and 10 interfaces and/or abstract classes. I too feel  the need of making the code "generic" and "reusable" but there has to be a limit.

Many times I've seen "religious wars" about these topics.

Read all the books you want, and take from them what you need. But after that, write reasonable code. Write useful stuff, that's the original reason why you started programming.

Comment: Your answer is one of the greatness things I've read in awhile. :)

Answer (score 4):

The two books complement each other. Effective Java is about best practices in writing java code. Design Patters describe a set of standard solutions to common software problems. The design patterns are language independent really, while Effective Java is obviously focused on the java language.

But my general approach is "always agree with Josh Bloch" ( unless Jon Skeet disagrees with him )

Comment: I agree, Design Patterns are language independent, and we certainly wrote Head First Design Patterns with that intention, even though we use Java to demonstrate the patterns. We also included a lot of basic "best practices" for programming. Josh Bloch's book is very good, so use both!

Answer (score 2):

Programming patterns are best practices.
They should be used sparingly.
Every design pattern tries to handle some form of variation.

For example strategy pattern tackles a variation in implementation
Which is basically a fancy way of saying it is a plug and play method.

Patterns result in flexible code, but they create a large amount of extra complexity in the code.

Maybe you want to take the book Applied Java Patterns next to those books you already have.
It's written by Olav Maarsen and Stephen Stelting. Also the root of all patterns are the Gang of Four, you might want to use their book as a refference as well.

Answer (score 0):

Design Pattern is not always good. Overuse of Design Pattern is bad.

Josh Bloch, however, is always right. Trust him and you are saved.

Forget Design Pattern. Josh Bloch's book gives you all the patterns you need.